# Count Distinct with 0 record?

Tags: sql, count

```
Study   Site    Status
A       1       Approved
        2       Closed
        3       Withdrawn
B       1       Closed
        2       Withdrawn
```

I have 2 tables of: Study and Site. Each site has a Status. After I join the 2 tables, I want to find out which Study does not have any site with Approved Status.

Basically, I want to write something that look for all the sites in the a study that does not have Approved Status. In this case, it would be Study B. I can't seem to think of a way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation to select studies without the status approved

```
<your join query here>    
group by study
having count(case when status = 'Approved' then 1 end) = 0
```

or you can use `not exists`

```
select * from site a
where not exists (
  select 1 from study b
  where b.status = 'Approved'
  and b.site_id = a.id
)
```

Comment: The NOT EXISTS works great and fast except I forgot to mentioned that I need to have an other criteria for the study with Approved Status only to narrow down the result. The Site has Status column and Study also has Status column as well. I am using SQL Server to clarify. Where should I place the first condition for the Study with Approved Status. I want to be able to Select column from the Study. I can't seem to use it if I put the table in the not exists ().

Comment: @ThaoLil' append `and a.status = 'Approved'`

Answer (score 2):

Outer join the tables, putting the criteria in the join condition, and use the where clause to filter our rows that *have* a join:

```
select a.*
from site a
left join study b on s.id = b.site
    and b.status = 'Approved'
where b.site is null
```

Although this may seem like a weird query, it's actually very efficient and works because missed joins have all nulls in the columns - hence the where clause - and you can put non-key criteria on join conditions.

Comment: *NOT EXISTS* version is the most efficient one. Check here for in-depth analysis by **Aaron Bertrand**  http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join.

Comment: @NoDisplayName . . . Aaron's analysis is going to be specific to SQL Server (and in this case, possibly to a specific version of the software).  This question does not specify the database.

Comment: @nodis this query is usually efficient enough, and it looks quite elegant too, which surely counts for something! :)

Answer (score 0):

Be good if you provided the table description, but a not in will work, something like this.

```
select study from study where site not in (select site from site where status = 'Approved')
```

Comment: Beware of NULL's in the sub-select! If it has one (or more) site which is  NULL, the NOT IN becomes unknown, and no rows at all returned. To be "null safe" add site is not null to the sub-query's where clause. (Or use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT NULL.)